# Java Generics Type Arguments

Tags: java, generics

I have a quite hard time to get my code running. I have a generic method, that should sort and remove all duplicates from a given List. The items in the List, for example, String, all implement the Comparable interface.
Unfortunately, the code is not compiling and I don't understand why...

```
public static <T> List<T> distinctAndSort(List<T> s) {
    List<T> list = s.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(list); //Error
    return list;
}
```

This is what I got so far. Why can't I put my `List<T>` into sort? (The method sort(`List<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`) in the type Collections is not applicable to the arguments (`List<T>`).

In order to make my function work, what am I missing? Thx for every help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, `Collections.sort(List<T>)` must be a list of `Comparable`s, or you must supply a `Comparator<T>`. You can change your signature:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> distinctAndSort(List<T> s)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 10):

Declare your type variable as:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

This restricts your method only to be called with a type which implements `Comparable`, and thus you can call `Collections.sort` without an explicit `Comparator`.

Alternatively, you could provide a `Comparator<? super T>` as an additional parameter to the method, and pass it to `Collections.sort`.

Additionally, note that you can do the sorting with the stream API:

```
return s.stream()
    .distinct()
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```